# Incorrect values with multiple left joins (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a report. It is supposed to give me a list of the machines at a specific customer and the sum of hours and material that was put in to that machine.

In the following examples, I select the sum of materials and hours in different fields to make the problem clearer. But i really want to sum the material an hours, then group them by the machine field.

I can query the list of machine and cost of hours without problems.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`customer`.`PREFIX`, `wo`.`machine_id`) AS `machine`, 
       ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(`wohours`.`length` * `wohours`.`price`), 0), 2) AS `hours`

FROM `wo`
JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`id`=`wo`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `wohours` ON `wohours`.`wo_id`=`wo`.`id` AND `wohours`.`wo_customer_id`=`wo`.`customer_id` 
                    AND `wohours`.`wo_machine_id`=`wo`.`machine_id` AND `wohours`.`date`>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH

WHERE `wo`.`customer_id`=1
GROUP BY `wo`.`machine_id`;
```

This gives me the correct values for hours. But when I add the material like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`customer`.`PREFIX`, `wo`.`machine_id`) AS `machine`, 
       ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(`wohours`.`length` * `wohours`.`price`), 0), 2) AS `hours`,
       ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(`womaterial`.`multiplier` * `womaterial`.`price`), 0), 2) AS `material`

FROM `wo`
JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`id`=`wo`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `wohours` ON `wohours`.`wo_id`=`wo`.`id` AND `wohours`.`wo_customer_id`=`wo`.`customer_id` 
           AND `wohours`.`wo_machine_id`=`wo`.`machine_id` AND `wohours`.`date`>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
LEFT JOIN `womaterial` ON `womaterial`.`wo_id`=`wo`.`id` AND `womaterial`.`wo_customer_id`=`wo`.`customer_id` 
           AND `womaterial`.`wo_machine_id`=`wo`.`machine_id` AND `wohours`.`date`>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH

WHERE `wo`.`customer_id`=1
GROUP BY `wo`.`machine_id`;
```

then both hour and material values are incorrect.

I have read other threads where people with similar problems could solve this by splitting it in multiple queries or subqueries. But I don't think that is possible in this case.

Any help is appreciated.

//John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other reading is correct.  You will need to put them into their own "subquery" for the join.  The reason you are probably getting invalid values is that the materials table has multiple records per machine, thus causing a Cartesian result from your original based on hours.  And you don't know which has many vs just one making it look incorrect.

So, I've written, and each inner-most query for pre-aggregating the woHours and woMaterial will produce a single record per "wo_id and machine_id" to join back to the wo table when finished.  Each of these queries has the criteria on the single customer ID you are trying to run it for.

Then, as re-joined to the work order (wo) table, it grabs all records and applies the ROUND() and COALESCE() in case no such hours or materials present.  So this is a return of something like

```
WO    Machine ID    Machine   Hours   Material
1     1             CustX 1   2       0
2     4             CustY 4   2.5     6.5
3     4             CustY 4   1.2     .5
4     1             CustX 1   1.5     1.2
```

Finally, you can now roll up the SUM() of all these entries into a single row per machine ID

```
Machine   Hours   Material
CustX 1   3.5     1.2
CustY 4   3.7     7.0


SELECT
      AllWO.Machine,
      SUM( AllWO.Hours ) Hours,
      SUM( AllWO.Material ) Material
   from
      ( SELECT
              wo.wo_id,
              wo.Machine_ID, 
              CONCAT(customer.PREFIX, wo.machine_id) AS machine, 
              ROUND( COALESCE( PreSumHours.MachineHours, 0), 2) AS hours,
              ROUND( COALESCE( PreSumMaterial.materialHours, 0), 2) AS material
           FROM 
              wo
                 JOIN customer 
                    ON wo.customer_id = customer.id

                 LEFT JOIN ( select wohours.wo_id,
                                    wohours.wo_machine_id,
                                    SUM( wohours.length * wohours.price ) as machinehours
                                from
                                   wohours 
                                where
                                       wohours.wo_customer_id = 1
                                   AND wohours.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
                                group by
                                   wohours.wo_id,
                                   wohours.wo_machine_id ) as PreSumHours
                    ON wo.id = PreSumHours.wo_id 
                    AND wo.machine_id = PreSumHours.wo_machine_id 

                 LEFT JOIN ( select womaterial.wo_id,
                                    womaterial.wo_machine_id,
                                    SUM( womaterial.length * womaterial.price ) as materialHours
                                from
                                   womaterial
                                where
                                       womaterial.wo_customer_id = 1
                                   AND womaterial.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
                                group by
                                   womaterial.wo_id,
                                   womaterial.wo_machine_id ) as PreSumMaterial
                    ON wo.id = PreSumMaterial.wo_id 
                    AND wo.machine_id = PreSumMaterial.wo_machine_id 
           WHERE 
              wo.customer_id = 1 ) AllWO
   group by
      AllWO.Machine_ID
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could join subqueries. There is a lot to learn. Anyway... thanks again.

Comment: How do you go about constructing a query like that? Do you just write them from top to bottom, or do you have a method for it?

Comment: @John, its from lots of practice.  I try to focus on what are the true pieces you want and try to filter out all the noise from that "thing" (with whatever grouping).  Then, move out a layer and see what else is needed at that next layer, etc.  In this case, I knew I needed two inner results on their own merits, then brought them out to the work order level.